# Updating label for specific version of a model in Model registry in Vertex AI

Tags: python, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have a model with several different versions in model registry in Vertex AI:
[image]

I want to change labels only for specific version programatically, using the python SDK, specifically the python-aiplatform https://github.com/googleapis/python-aiplatform/blob/v1.21.0/google/cloud/aiplatform/models.py.
When I created model instances of specific versions, all versions still got updated, it seems the version is ignored. I went through the source code, but did not find how to update the labels just for the specific version.
I tried this:

```
model6 = registry.get_model(6)
model6.version_id, model6
>>> ('6',
 <google.cloud.aiplatform.models.Model object at 0x7f5bb81d9f40> 
 resource name: projects/981769406988/locations/europe-west1/models/3411204038849462272)
model6.update(labels={"version":"something6"})
model4 = registry.get_model(4)
model4.version_id, model4
>>> ('4',
 <google.cloud.aiplatform.models.Model object at 0x7f5bb82287f0> 
 resource name: projects/981769406988/locations/europe-west1/models/3411204038849462272)
model4.update(labels={"version":"something4"})
```

and the result was[image]
clearly, the version6 got replaced.

Comment: According to the [google cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/model-registry/model-labels), there is no such information regarding programmatically updating the label for a specific version of a model in Model registry in Vertex AI. But you can edit labels for a specific version of a model using GUI. If you want this feature to be implemented, you can open a new [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) on the issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's not possible to do using `from google.cloud import aiplatform`, but it's possible using the lower-level `from google.cloud import aiplatform_v1` library. Unfortunately it's tricky to obtain the current labels for specific version of a model, you need to obtain the list of all versions of the model and this provides you correct labels.

```py
from google.cloud import aiplatform
from google.cloud import aiplatform_v1
a_model = aiplatform.Model.list(project='981769406988', location='europe-west1',
                                filter=f'display_name="version-experiment-model"')[0]
a_model.versioned_resource_name, a_model.labels
a_model_v1 = a_model.api_client.get_model(
    name=a_model.versioned_resource_name
)
a_model_v1.name, a_model_v1.labels
```

will give you only the labels for the whole model, not the specific version.

In order to obtain the correct labels, you need to do

```py
a_model_v1.name == a_model.versioned_resource_name
a_model_list = a_model.api_client.list_model_versions(name=a_model.resource_name)
a_model_list_list = list(a_model_list)
the_model_version = [m for m in a_model_list_list if m.name == a_model.versioned_resource_name][0]
the_model_version.labels, type(the_model_version.labels)
```

which gives you the correct labels, and then you can update them by

```py
model_v12 = aiplatform_v1.Model(
    name=a_model.versioned_resource_name,
    version_id=a_model.version_id,
    display_name=a_model.display_name,
    labels=the_model_version.labels,
)
model_v12.labels['version_2'] = "0_0_5"
request = aiplatform_v1.UpdateModelRequest(model=model_v12)
response = model.api_client.update_model(request=request)
```

currently there is an open issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/297582022 to have a better way to do this, but until then, this is the best way to go.